# Url.Action ASP.NET how do i redirect?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

I want to redirect a link using url,action(...)to an external site
http://external.com/Page.html

How do i do that in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the local ASP.Net site does not have knowledge of the external site, just enter your code in plain Html:

```
 <a href="http://external......">....</a>
```

If you need to calculate parameters:

```
 <a href="http://external......?<%= MyParamsCorrectlyEncoded() %>">....</a>
```

If you are using MVC (your question mentions Url.Action) you can use [AttributeEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492240.aspx) to encode the attributes to the external site.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that would be it.